# Euler function not giving results

Tags: python, matplotlib

We have programmed an Euler function to study population changes.

He used a `while` loop to keep our values in a biological range (no births, etc.). When we run the script, the plot axis range from -0.6 to +0.6 and no graph is actually drawn.

Does anyone know what is wrong with the code?

```
t=np.zeros((n+1))

for i in range (n):
     t[i+1]=t[i]+dt

s = np.zeros((n+1))
z = np.zeros((n+1))
r = np.zeros((n+1))
s[0] = N-1
z[0] =1
i=0


while s[i]>0 and s[i] <N and z[i] < N and z[i] > 0 and r[i] >0 and r[i] <N and i<n: 
    s[i+1] = s[i]+dt*(-b*s[i]*z[i])
    z[i+1] = z[i]+dt*(b*s[i]*z[i]-a*z[i])
    r[i+1] = r[i]+dt*(a*z[i])
    i=i+1

self.trace(t,s,r,z,i)

def trace(self,t, s, r, z, i):

       plt.plot(t[:i],s[:i],'b')
       plt.plot(t[:i],z[:i],'r')
       plt.plot(t[:i],r[:i],'y')
       plt.show()
```

Comment: For the record: Saying "we are kind of running out of time" won't get you answers any faster. Having a good question will -- Go through and read whatever catches your eye in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and apply that knowledge to your post, and it'll help way more than saying "this is my problem, help, I don't have much time". Of course, your question is still pretty decent as-is; really all you should add is a screenshot of the graphless graph and maybe a Paint mockup of what you want.

Comment: Please use more descriptive variable names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see `r` initialized as:

```
r = np.zeros((n+1))
```

Then in the while loop conditions you require `r[i] >0`.

Since `i=0`, `r[i]=0` and the condition will be false so the loop will not execute.

Perhaps you are missing an initialization of `r[0] = ...`

Comment: Thank you so much it does indeed solve it ! I changed > into >=.